# How to set all columns to the same value?

Tags: sql, nvarchar, sql-scripts

i need help to understand How may i set all nvarchar value with same ides in table to the same id's nvarchar value of table b?

```
insert into TableA
select CAST(Id  as nvarchar)
from TableB
where ID in (select ID] from TableA)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generalized script which you can change according to your needs.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```